# Function works as object in global env but not from package

Tags: r, raster

I have a function to create sample variograms of raster layers. The function takes a `RasterStack` or `RasterBrick` and returns a list with one variogram per layer. The function works fine when it's loaded in the `.GlobalEnv` but when I use it from the package I get an error that says: 
`Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘nlayers’ for signature ‘"numeric"’` 
 The traceback said something was going wrong in the line where I use the `rasterToPoints` function, and also in the line where I use `lapply` on `dlist`, but I have no idea why `nlayers()` is being used at all, or why it's only an issue when trying to use the function from the package.

Here is the function with roxygen2 comments:

```
#' Create sample variograms of CHIRPS data
#'
#' @name sampvar-chrp
#' @title Create sample variograms of CHIRPS data
#'
#' @param data RasterStack of CHIRPS images
#' @return List of sample variograms
#' @examples
#' data(chrprf)
#' sampvar_chrp(chrprf)
#' @export
sampvar_chrp <- function(data) {
  dlist <- as.list(data)
  spdf <- lapply(dlist, function(x){
    names(x) <- "rain"
    pts <- rasterToPoints(x, spatial = TRUE)
  })
  rsamp <- lapply(spdf, function(x){
    s <- x[sample(1:length(x), size = 150), ]
  })
  chrp_vario <- lapply(rsamp, function(x){
    v <- variogram(object = rain ~ 1, data = x)
  })
  return(chrp_vario)
}
```

I appreciate any advice!

Edit: I think (at least part of) the issue is that `data` is not successfully getting converted to a list when running the function from the package. I edited the function, redocumented, reinstalled, and got the `"error"` print statement. So it seems like `as.list(data)` works in the global environment but is not working from my package. Here is the edited function:

```
#' Create sample variograms of CHIRPS data
#'
#' @name sampvar_chrp
#' @title Create sample variograms of CHIRPS data
#'
#' @param data RasterStack of CHIRPS images
#' @return List of sample variograms
#' @importFrom raster rasterToPoints
#' @examples
#' data(chrprf)
#' sampvar_chrp(chrprf)
#' @export
sampvar_chrp <- function(data) {
  dlist <- as.list(data)
  if (is.list(dlist) == TRUE) {
    spdf <- lapply(dlist, function(x){
      names(x) <- "rain"
      pts <- rasterToPoints(x, spatial = TRUE)
    })
    rsamp <- lapply(spdf, function(x){
      s <- x[sample(1:length(x), size = 150), ]
    })
    chrp_vario <- lapply(rsamp, function(x){
      v <- variogram(object = rain ~ 1, data = x)
    })
    return(chrp_vario)
  } else { print("error")}

}
```

Comment: If `rasterToPoints` is from a different package, have you imported that function/package? There is no import directive in what you've shared.

Comment: @joran Yes it is from a different package, the `raster` package, and I have that set in the `Imports` section of the DESCRIPTION. I also tried changing that line to `raster::rasterToPoints` and redocumenting/installing my package and it had no effect, I got the same error.

Comment: In addition to the `Imports:` section of `DESCRIPTION`, do you have either `importFrom(raster,rasterToPoints)` or `import(raster)` in `NAMESPACE`?

Comment: @r2evans No, I do not, all I have in my `NAMESPACE` is `export` lines of the functions I've documented. I do not have an .R file with roxygen comments for my package. I'm guessing that's where I would define the `import` statements for `NAMESPACE`? I am new to R and wasn't sure if that component was necessary.

Comment: One good reference for packages is Hadley's [R packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/), in which you can find specific discussion on [Namespaces](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html) (with/without roxygen) and [Object documentation](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html). I personally prefer to include the `@importFrom raster rasterToPoints` in the specific function requiring it; in addition to locally documenting requirements, if I ever delete the function from the package, the import requirement will be taken care of the next time I regenerate `NAMESPACE` (e.g., `devtools::document(...)`).

Comment: @r2evans That is a good point about documenting the imports locally. I just tried including `@importFrom raster rasterToPoints` in the function comments, but it did not help the error. I will keep playing around with that and hope something changes...

Comment: To be certain, did you rerun `devtools::document` and then either `devtools:: install` or some other build/install sequence?

Comment: @r2evans Yes, i did. The `NAMESPACE` now includes `importFrom(raster, rasterToPoints)`. I've tried reinstalling locally and from GitHub, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at `raster::rasterToPoints`, you can see that

```
head(rasterToPoints)

#1 function (x, fun = NULL, spatial = FALSE, ...)                                      
#2 {                                                                                   
#3     nl <- nlayers(x)
```

The first thing it calls is `nlayers`. The error message indicates that it gets a `numeric` vector, whereas it expects a `Raster*` object.

The problem seems to be that your variable `data` is not a `Raster*` object. So you need to go (at least) one step back to see what is going on.

Comment: That's what's so weird about the error though, `data` is without question a `Raster*` object (`RasterBrick` specifically, so each element of `dlist` is a `RasterLayer`, for which `rasterToPoints` should work). When I test the function in the `.GlobalEnv` with a `RasterBrick`, it works as expected. But when I write `rm(sampvar_chrp)` and try to call the function from the package with the same input `RasterBrick`, I get this error. Seems like something is going on with my package, but I'm not sure where.

Comment: Can you provide a small and reproducible sample data that triggers the error? It's really difficult to help when we cannot trigger it ourselves.

Comment: @r2evans Got it!! The issue was that `raster` package has its own `as.list` function, and it seems like that was getting used in the Global environment but not from the package. I added `importFrom raster as.list` to the function documentation as you suggested, and it works! Thanks so much for your help!